# Need assistance in adding devlink to react app

Tags: reactjs, webflow

-I created react app using npx create-react-app

- created test components on webflow
- installed the devlink cli and and created a config file in the root directory of the react app.
- on the devlink documentation it uses nextjs and the  is placed in the layout.tsx file.

My question is how do i do the similar thing for react? where do i put the  element and how?